# В чем разница между jQurey событиями focusin и focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код с событием **focusin**  который по мне делает тоже самое что и событие **focus**,  не могу понять в чем разница.

```html
<input id="one" type="text" placeholder="one" >
<input  id="two" type="text" placeholder="two">




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //Focus Event
   $('#one').on('focus', function() {
      console.log('focus');
   });
   //Focus in Event
   $('#two').on('focusin', function() {
      console.log('focusin');
   });
   
  
</script>
```

*Есть ли* какие то **глубокие различия** в *этих событиях* ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focusin/ «This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling)»

Comment: В вашем примере разницы нет. В примере в документации `focusin` вешается на тег `p`, при этом никакого события `focus` у него не бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Событие focusin отправляется элементу, когда он или любой элемент внутри него получает фокус. Это отличается от фокусного события тем, что он поддерживает обнаружение события фокуса на родительских элементах (другими словами, он поддерживает пузырьки событий).